# SQLAlchemy tutorial on select statement

Tags: sqlalchemy

Im trying to follow sqlalchemy tutorial  from the below site,

```
http://www.rmunn.com/sqlalchemy-tutorial/tutorial.html
```

Im really stuck while doing the select statements,

As per the tutorial,the selects are done as below but I dont understand the part where he uses "users.c.name == 'John'" in the users.select. what is the "users.c" in the statement?

shouln't users.name will just suffice?

```
from sqlalchemy import *

# Let's re-use the same database as before
db = create_engine('sqlite:///tutorial.db')

db.echo = True  # We want to see the SQL we're creating

metadata = BoundMetaData(db)

# The users table already exists, so no need to redefine it. Just
# load it from the database using the "autoload" feature.
users = Table('users', metadata, autoload=True)

def run(stmt):
    rs = stmt.execute()
    for row in rs:
        print row

# Most WHERE clauses can be constructed via normal comparisons
s = users.select(users.c.name == 'John')
run(s)
s = users.select(users.c.age < 40)
run(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer the `c` part of the question:**

`users` is a [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) instance which represents a table in the database
`users.c` is a [`Table.c`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.c), simply an alias to to [`Table.columns`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.columns), so this is how one accesses table columns.

**As for the tutorial:**

The link you provided refers to the sqlalchemy version 0.2. Needless to say, it is very-very old. Please consider official [sqlalchemy documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/) and specifically for your case the [SQL Expression Language tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#selecting).